# Continuous Integration Using Salesforce DX

Tags: salesforcedx

I am setting up Continuous Integration Using Salesforce DX. I have set the environment variable using set and still I am getting

> ERROR:  client identifier invalid.

I am using below command

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid ${CONSUMER_KEY} --username ${HUB_USERNAME} --jwtkeyfile C:/certificates/server.key --instanceurl
```

Comment: If you just setup the connected app, you have to wait a few minutes . Has it been more than 10 minutes?

Comment: Its been more than a day i created the connect app.. Let me know if its correct, i added User environment like ( Variable = CONSUMER_KEY ) in windows PC

Comment: What CI architecture are you using, and how are you setting the consumer key in the CI environment?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the invalid Oauth Client ID. I suggest to print the value of ${CONSUMER_KEY} before running the command to make sure it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the Consumer Key from the Connected App and not the Consumer Secret for the -jwtkeyfile param.